# Use kotlin's Unit (or any other object) type in android layout

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, android-databinding

Looking into Kotlin's [`Unit`](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.1.3/core/builtins/src/kotlin/Unit.kt#L22) type, which is an `object` basically representing Java's `void`.

On some occasions I'd like to use a `PublishSubject<Unit>` in a `onClick` data binding to basically just signal the click. The android xml looks like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:layout_width="148dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.navigateSubject.onNext(Unit)}" />
```

Within the `layout` I'm introducing the type:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.TestViewModel"/>        
        <import type="kotlin.Unit"/>
    </data>
    [...]
```

However the call of the object type in this way is of course not possible, has anybody found a way to use the `Unit` type in android xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `Unit.INSTANCE`, as in Java code.